# linkedin talent insight api

Tags: linkedin-api

I am working on linkedin talent insights for our organization. Currently we manually downloading the reports from linkedin Talentpool. We are manually downloading more than 500 reports based on different search criteria. Is there any way to automate the download? I am looking for APIs for downloading the same reports and so that we can programmatically download the reports.
Any input will be much appreciated.

Comment: We have same problem. Looking for any solution on this regards